# Debugging which destructor is freezing the return of my function

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a function that returns an int, but uses an object called `Handler` inside of it:

```
int handler() {
    Handler myHandler;
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

The function never returns because it's getting stuck on the Handler destruction. I did:

```
#define ALOGV(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)

class Handler{
    Handler(){}
    ~Handler(){ALOGV("destructing handler...")}
    //some private members
};
```

I can see `"destrucing handler..."` on Android's JNI output, but the function never returns a value. This means that the destruction of `myHandler` never finishes. I placed `ALOGV` in the destructor of all objects contained in `Handler` and also in all objects that these objects contain, but I dont see the log of any of these, only of `~Handler`.

Is it possible that `__android_log_print` is buffering the print calls?

Is my assumption wrong that I should see the output of each destuctor before the object is destructed?

When handler is going to be destructed, it first calls its destructor, then the destructor of each object it holds is called, which should call their destructors and print on the screen.

Comment: Seems like something you can easily test by simply wrapping the `myHandler` object inside another set of `{}` braces so that it gets destructed before the `return` instead of after. `int handler() { { Handler myHandler; //... } return 0; }` Then you can debug the entire destructor before the `return` is reached, maybe even put another print statement before the `return` to see if it flushes the destructor's log messages.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes I done that and confirmed the problem is because of `Handler`. The destructor of `Handler` does nothing, so the problem is on the destructor of its objects

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs But my point is, this will make it easier for you to debug *those other object destructors*, by making the destructor of `Handler` itself more deterministic.  YOU decide when it gets called, so you can step through it when you want to.  The other way to do that is to use `new`/`delete` instead of scope braces.